# Delay Between WebScraping

Tags: php, dom, scrape

I am using webscraping to get data from a certain website using SIMPLE PHP DOM PARSER CLASS
There are few problems i am facing.

1. There are two websites which are returning an error HTTP 403 forbidden
2. Secondly As per the below code i am scraping 9 products from 9 URLS after 8 URL's i get error i shuffle the urls and checked single one but its not the url its the execution time or web requests may be allowed  as i get Appache windows error .I tried to delay it using 
      sleep(10);
   it didnt worked any help would be highly appreciated

   ```
         $url = $this->urls['abc'].'Product/1/1_oz_Gold_American_Eagle___Random_Year.aspx';
           $regex = 'span[id=ctl10_ctl00_tc1_TabPnlProdDesc_lblbuyprice]';
             $data=$this->getCoinVal($url,$regex);     

                      $this->update_scrap(GAE_1,APMEX,strip_tags($this->r_dollar($data)),$url);
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this for time delay in bracket ()

```
  import time

  time.sleep(sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the error was due to memory leaks in apache server

so using these two lines will make it work .

```
              $dom->clear();  
              unset($dom);
```

where $dom is object of parser class